# Can't use prepare statement in pdo+odbc+Ms Sql db setting

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I followed the instruction in here

[Accessing Microsoft SQL Server from PHP on Ubuntu using PDO, ODBC and FreeTDS](https://secure.kitserve.org.uk/content/accessing-microsoft-sql-server-php-ubuntu-using-pdo-odbc-and-freetds)

to set up odbc.

and then somehow I got it worked but not totally. If I use a full query statement, it return

result correctly, but if I bind data later, no response from DB side... I just get the chrome

"No Data Received" page.

```
Environment: PHP Version 5.3.2-1  ubuntu4.26
```

My code:

```
$conn=new PDO("odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=Mssql host; Port=1433;
 Database=dbname; UID=userid; PWD=pw");
```

if I use this:

```
$sql="Select * from customer where email='abc@gmail.com'";

$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
```

it fetch data from DB correctly.

But if I use this

```
$sql="Select * from customer where email= ? ";

$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('abc@gmail.com'));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
```

I get the chrome "No data received" with a sad face page icon.

I have try catch around those code, but ...it doesn't help in this case.

I don't know is that I miss something during the odbc set up or it's something else.

Actually, I wonder which driver/way you guys use to work with a **MS SQL DB**(2008) with php in

**Linux (ubuntu) environment**? I was using `dblib` at beginning (and it works ) but after

reading more, I found PHP doesn't suggest people to use `dblib`, they think we should use

`odbc`, but it didn't really work.

Comment: Hello @Anna , did you ever find a solution to this? Stuck in the same scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your connection variables are named differently:

```
$conn=new PDO("odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=Mssql host; Port=1433;
 Database=dbname; UID=userid; PWD=pw");
```

and you then  you have

```
$stmt=$connNc->prepare($sql);
```

They must be the same.

Comment: Thank you I already corrected the code...but in the real code I use the same variable. Then I got the strange result.

Comment: @Anna I dont see a problem, try `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: @AhmedDaou I'm in the same scenario and I already set that attribute. It doesn't help as Chrome shows an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. Any other ideas?

Comment: just post a question and send me the link, I will look at it